# Which methodologies can be used in machine learning research?

Tags: methodology

I am investigating some machine learning algorithms (Perceptron and KNN) and I'm confused in the methodology section of my report. I am evaluating the performance of the 2 algorithms. Which methodology should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the methodology is to determine the prediction capability of the models after the learning on a validation set. The algorithm with the highest prediction accuracy wins.

Comment: With reference to your answer, please what methodologies are there to determine the prediction capability or accuracy of the algorithms? can i say that any form of cross validation  is a methodology?

Answer (score 1):

The methodology (or Methods) section should explain to the reader how you performed the experiment, and why you chose these methods. In your case, you should ask question such as

- How the data was obtained? Why is this data good for the experiment?
- What pre-processing was done? Why these pre-proc techniques?
- How were the algorithms compared (K-Fold CV, Test/Train split)? Why use these methods? What was the comparison metrics? Why these metrics and not others?

Keep in mind that this section should be written clearly and without much detail. For a more comprehensive writing guide, check the [USC Guide](http://libguides.usc.edu/writingguide/methodology) (it's for social sciences, but still apply).

Comment: i am using an online dataset from UCI ML repository. Is there a general method to know that the data i have obtained is enough for my research?